# nodejs- socket.io server pushes same data for all users

Tags: node.js, sockets, socket.io

The socket.io implementation I did is wrong. I am trying to implement long polling on a mysql data.

For this demo, I'm fetching user data for each user connected to the long-polling server I created. Each user will pass his unique user_id to the server to fetch the data related to him/her. (In real app, I wanna fetch user notifications)

Users get connected to the server and server does long polling from the DB also. But the problem is, same data is pushed back to the client even though I'm passing unique ids from client side.

User 1 passed id 5 and user 2 passes id 3. Both these users are getting same data as response (user 1's data)

Here's the **client side code**:

```
var user_id = 5; //hardcoded for now, but in real its fetched from a form
var params = {
    userId: user_id,
};
// create a new websocket
var socket = io.connect('http://localhost:8000', { query: params });

// on message received we print all the data inside the #container div
socket.on('notification', function (data) {
    console.log(data);

});
```

Here's the server side code:

```
var app = require('http').createServer(handler),
    io = require('socket.io').listen(app),
    fs = require('fs'),
    mysql = require('mysql'),
    connectionsArray = [],
    connection = mysql.createConnection({
        host: 'localhost',
        user: 'root',
        password: '',
        database: 'dumydb',
        port: 3306
    }),
    POLLING_INTERVAL = 5000,
    pollingTimer;

// If there is an error connecting to the database
connection.connect(function (err) {
    // connected! (unless `err` is set)
    if (err) {
        console.log(err);
    }
});

// creating the server ( localhost:8000 )
app.listen(8000);

// on server started we can load our client.html page
function handler(req, res) {
    fs.readFile(__dirname + '/client.html', function (err, data) {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
            res.writeHead(500);
            return res.end('Error loading client.html');
        }
        res.writeHead(200);
        res.end(data);
    });
}

// creating a new websocket to keep the content updated without any AJAX request
io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {

    var userId = socket.handshake.query.userId;
    // starting the loop only if at least there is one user connected
    if (!connectionsArray.length) {
        pollingLoop(userId);
    }

    socket.on('disconnect', function () {
        var socketIndex = connectionsArray.indexOf(socket);
        console.log('socketID = %s got disconnected', socketIndex);
        if (~socketIndex) {
            connectionsArray.splice(socketIndex, 1);
        }
    });

    console.log('A new socket is connected!');
    connectionsArray.push(socket);

});

var pollingLoop = function (userId) {
    var params = [userId];
    // Doing the database query
    var tempQuery = `SELECT full_name FROM users WHERE id=?`;
    var query = connection.query(tempQuery, params),
        users = []; // this array will contain the result of our db query

    // setting the query listeners
    query
        .on('error', function (err) {
            // Handle error, and 'end' event will be emitted after this as well
            updateSockets(err);
        })
        .on('result', function (user) {
            // it fills our array looping on each user row inside the db
            users.push(user);
        })
        .on('end', function () {
            // loop on itself only if there are sockets still connected
            if (connectionsArray.length) {

                pollingTimer = setTimeout(function () { pollingLoop(userId) }, POLLING_INTERVAL);

                updateSockets({
                    users: users
                });
            } else {
                console.log('The server timer was stopped because there are no more socket connections on the app')
            }
        });
};

var updateSockets = function (data) {
    // adding the time of the last update
    data.time = new Date();
    // sending new data to all the sockets connected
    connectionsArray.forEach(function (tmpSocket) {
        tmpSocket.volatile.emit('notification', data);
    });
};

console.log('Please use your browser to navigate to http://localhost:8000');
```

This is the tutorial I'm following: [Link](https://github.com/vpdeva/long-poll)

Can anyone help me figure out why same data is being pushed to all users? Thanks!

**UPDATE 1**

I tried the solutions provided by Theo and Abdul Rab Memon
Changed my updateSockets() but now the data is getting pushed only to the first client connected. I did a console.log()
Take a look at this:

[image]

**UPDATE 2**: `package.json`

```
{
  "name": "nodejs-MySQL-push-notifications-demo",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "nodejs-MySQL-push-notifications-demo",
  "main": "server.js",
  "dependencies": {
    "express": "^4.16.2",
    "mysql": "~2.5.4",
    "socket.io": "~1.3.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {},
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "start": "node server.js"
  },
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "git://github.com/GianlucaGuarini/nodejs-MySQL-push-notifications-demo.git"
  },
  "author": "Gianluca Guarini",
  "license": "BSD-2-Clause",
  "bugs": {
    "url": "https://github.com/GianlucaGuarini/nodejs-MySQL-push-notifications-demo/issues"
  },
  "homepage": "https://github.com/GianlucaGuarini/nodejs-MySQL-push-notifications-demo"
}
```

Comment: updateSockets function emit all socket notification event, so same data is being pushed to all users.

Comment: so, what should I change there? I'm pretty new to this stuff. @Cr. 25

Comment: @AnnaBelle, can you provide a git repo to debug? Because its best to be on exact packages you are using.

Comment: https://github.com/vpdeva/long-poll  I'm sampling code from this repo. @Tarun Lalwani

Answer (score 6):

```
var app = require('http').createServer(handler),
    io = require('socket.io').listen(app),
    fs = require('fs'),
    mysql = require('mysql'),
    connectionsArray = [],
    connection = mysql.createConnection({
        host: 'localhost',
        user: 'root',
        password: '',
        database: 'dumydb',
        port: 3306
    }),
    POLLING_INTERVAL = 5000,
    pollingTimer;

// If there is an error connecting to the database
connection.connect(function (err) {
    // connected! (unless `err` is set)
    if (err) {
        console.log(err);
    }
});

// creating the server ( localhost:8000 )
app.listen(8000);

// on server started we can load our client.html page
function handler(req, res) {
    fs.readFile(__dirname + '/client.html', function (err, data) {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
            res.writeHead(500);
            return res.end('Error loading client.html');
        }
        res.writeHead(200);
        res.end(data);
    });
}

// creating a new websocket to keep the content updated without any AJAX request
io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {

    var userId = socket.handshake.query.userId;
    connectionsArray.push(socket);
    // starting the loop only if at least there is one user connected
    if (connectionsArray.length) {
        var socketIndex = connectionsArray.indexOf(socket);
        pollingLoop(userId, socketIndex);
    }

    socket.on('disconnect', function () {
        var socketIndex = connectionsArray.indexOf(socket);
        console.log('socketID = %s got disconnected', socketIndex);
        if (~socketIndex) {
            connectionsArray.splice(socketIndex, 1);
        }
    });

    console.log('A new socket is connected!');

});

var pollingLoop = function (userId, socketIndex) {
    var params = [userId];
    // Doing the database query
    var tempQuery = `SELECT full_name FROM users WHERE id=?`;
    var query = connection.query(tempQuery, params),
        users = []; // this array will contain the result of our db query

    // setting the query listeners
    query
        .on('error', function (err) {
            // Handle error, and 'end' event will be emitted after this as well
            updateSockets(err, socketIndex);
        })
        .on('result', function (user) {
            // it fills our array looping on each user row inside the db
            users.push(user);
        })
        .on('end', function () {
            // loop on itself only if there are sockets still connected
            if (connectionsArray.length) {

                pollingTimer = setTimeout(function () { pollingLoop(userId) }, POLLING_INTERVAL);

                updateSockets({
                    users: users
                }, socketIndex);
            } else {
                console.log('The server timer was stopped because there are no more socket connections on the app')
            }
        });
};

var updateSockets = function (data, socketIndex) {
    // adding the time of the last update
    data.time = new Date();
    // sending new data to all the sockets connected
    connectionsArray[socketIndex].volatile.emit('notification', data);
};

console.log('Please use your browser to navigate to http://localhost:8000');
```

In the updateSockets method you're iterating over connectionsArray and emitting 'notification' event with data on each socket that's present in connectionsArray, you need to pass the socket from socket.on('connection', callback(socket)) to pollingLoop method and from pollingLoop to updatSocket method.

Comment: This is not working, I don't know why. I'm testing this from multiple browsers on my PC. Socket returns output only to the first browser that connects. I established a connection from Chrome, Firefox and Firefox developer edition browsers. Output is emitted only to one of them. @Abdul Rab Memon

Comment: socket.volatile.emit('notification', data); from your code emits data only to the first socket connected. It doesn't push data to other sockets connected. The approach you mentioned is good only if there is one active connection. @Abdul Rab Memon

Comment: The output you're getting, I wasn't expecting, honestly I don't get why is that happening. I can not run this code until you provide me package.json file for this. I have edited the code try that if that works.@AnnaBelle

Comment: Okay, I will add package,json soon. @Abdul Rab Memon

Comment: Added package.json. Updated the question details. @Abdul Rab Memon

Comment: Yes, I tried the edited code. Edited code doesn't do long polling, only sockets get connected. In your first code, long polling did happen but the data was getting emitted only to the first client. @Abdul Rab Memon

Comment: just remove '!' from if (!connectionsArray.length).

Comment: This code works, emits unique data to each client but there's an error. It comes when I disconnect a client (close the browser tab)-  TypeError: Cannot read property 'emit' of undefined. This error is thrown from this line - connectionsArray[socketIndex].volatile.emit('notification', data);- inside updateSockets() @Abdul Rab Memon

Comment: Fixed that error by checking if(connectionsArray[socketIndex]) before emitting the data. @Abdul Rab Memon

Comment: If my answer is what you wanted you can accept it. That would be nice. @AnnaBelle

Comment: I'm refactoring the code and running test cases. @Abdul Rab Memon

Comment: There is an issue with this code. It does push data to clients but when multiple clients are connected to a socket, correct data is not pushed to the clients. Mismatch occurs! Someone else's data is being sent to someone else. @Abdul Rab Memon

Answer (score 3):

Since you mentioned that you want to fetch **data related to the user**, you need to emit to the **specific client socket**. To do this, you need to save the socket.id of the client every time they connect. You can do it with something like this:

```
var userList = {};

io.on('connection', (socket) => {
   usersList[socket.handshake.query.userId].socket_id = socket.id;
});
```

After a successful polling, you can send to specific user like this 
 
**Note the additional parameter userId that you can pass from pollingLoop**

```
var updateSockets = function (data, userId) {
    // adding the time of the last update
    data.time = new Date();
    // sending new data to the specific socket connected
    io.sockets.to(userList[userId].socket_id).emit('notification', data);
};
```

You may try to use namespaces or rooms to send to a group. so instead of

```
connectionsArray.forEach(function (tmpSocket) {
    tmpSocket.volatile.emit('notification', data);
});
```

you can use **namespaces**

**Client code**

```
var socket = io.connect('http://localhost:8000/your_name_space', { query: params });
```

**Server code**

```
io.of('/your_name_space').emit('notification', data_to_be_sent);
```

or **groups** - Please refer to this link for more info on rooms https://socket.io/docs/rooms-and-namespaces/

Comment: what version of socket.io are you using? it is supposed to contain a random hash.

Comment: socket.io-client: 2.0.4. I get socket id in client side using this code: socket.on('connect', () => {socketId = socket.id;}); But I'm not getting the same in server side.

Comment: a good aproach also in this case is use socket.join(USER_ID_FROM_CLIENT), then socket.to(USER_ID_FROM_CLIENT).emit('notification', YOUR_NOTIF_DATA);